# How to identify cause of 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error and handle in Apache httpd

Tags: php, apache-http-server

I got the error 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable when i refreshed the page 4 or 5 times within a second.

`Service Unavailable The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.`

I'm using apache httpd version 2.4.58
Thanks in advance,

The page is returning normal after wait around 1 minute before refresh again. how can we detect its cause of error since application project is not wrong any?

Comment: You'll need to check the webserver logs (both Apache and PHP-FPM), probably timeouts or resource depletion.